# Mutillidae Error Blank Page when setting up database

Tags: php, linux, apache, mariadb, debian

I'm currently having issues using mutillidae. When i go too http://localhost/mutillidae/set-up-database.php their is no screen available and everything is blank. I have attached the screen shot as well. This is the error that displays on the Mutillidae home screen
[image]
Database Error message: Failed to connect to MySQL database. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
im currently using Debian Linux.

Comment: It's clear your login/password are not correct or the root user is not allowed to connect @localhost. By experience it's probably a wrong credentials in the Multillidae config

Comment: Check your webserver error log for clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Inazo is correct, here's a breakdown of how to get it up and running.

I just wrote a Medium article on this, and ran into the same issues, but I'm not going to self-promote my feed and will just lay out the steps here for you :)

1. Make sure you are running the LAMP stack (Linux, Apache,MySQL, PHP) For those instructions: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04

Ignore the secure configuration steps for MySQL, since we are setting the VM up as a host-only network.

The following commands you will need are as follows:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install apache2

sudo ufw app list

sudo ufw allow in “Apache”

sudo apt install mysql-server

sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

After these commands are run, proceed to Step 4 — Creating a Virtual Host for your Website

Within /var/www

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/webpwnized/mutillidae
```

You should see a new Mutillidae folder

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mutillidae.conf
```

Paste in the following contents, and save the file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mutillidae
    ServerAlias mutillidae.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mutillidae
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mutillidae-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/mutillidae-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

[image: file content]

```
sudo a2ensite Mutillidae (this will enable the site)

sudo a2dissite 000-default (disables the default Apache site)

sudo systemctl reload apache2
```

Now open Firefox and browse to your internal IP. You will be presented with the following error

[image: Mutillidae Error]

```
sudo MySQL
```

```
ALTER USER ‘root’@’localhost’ IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY ‘mutillidae’;
```

This is changing the root password to mutillidae

```
sudo nano /var/html/mutillidae/includes/database-config.inc
```

Change the DB password to mutillidae and save the file

[image: mutillidae DB Info]

Now refresh FireFox and you should see the setup DB screen. The important line is the fact that the DB mutillidae is unknown, as long as this error exists, we can setup the DB via the click here option

If you run into any issues with this, please don't hesitate to reach out. I hope this helps, and am sorry for such a late response :(

Answer (score 0):

probably you're using another php version. Multillidae runs on php 7.4
If you dont have the 7.4 php version, you can install with:

> sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https -y
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y
>
> sudo apt update
>
> sudo apt upgrade
>
> sudo apt install php-7.4 libapache2-mod-php7.4 -y
>
> sudo systemctl restart apache2
>
> sudo apt install php7.4-fpm libapache2-mod-fcgid
>
> sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif && sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
>
> sudo systemctl restart apache2

if you already have version 7.4 you can run:

> sudo a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif && sudo a2enconf php7.4-fpm
>
> sudo systemctl restart apache2